# Flask use oauth verification to use google drive api

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api

I am currently using Oauth2.0 to log into my Flask app. I have that working as intended. Now I want to use the same creds I got from logging in to be able to send requests to the Google drive api. Im not really sure where to start, the docs are difficult to follow.

note: I have activated the Google Drive api in the developer console.

Here is the code for the login callback.

globally:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = config['google_client_id']
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = config['google_client_secret']
GOOGLE_DISCOVERY_URL = (
    "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
)

client = WebApplicationClient(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
```

view function:

```py
@bp.route('/login/callback')
def callback():
    # Get authorization code Google sent back to you
    code = request.args.get("code")
    # Find out what URL to hit to get tokens that allow you to ask for
    # things on behalf of a user
    google_provider_cfg = get_google_provider_cfg()
    token_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["token_endpoint"]  
    token_url, headers, body = client.prepare_token_request(
    token_endpoint,
        authorization_response=request.url,
        redirect_url=request.base_url,
        code=code
    )
    token_response = requests.post(
        token_url,
        headers=headers,
        data=body,
        auth=(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET),
    )

    # Parse the tokens!
    client.parse_request_body_response(json.dumps(token_response.json()))
    # Now that you have tokens (yay) let's find and hit the URL
    # from Google that gives you the user's profile information,
    # including their Google profile image and email
    userinfo_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["userinfo_endpoint"]
    uri, headers, body = client.add_token(userinfo_endpoint)
    userinfo_response = requests.get(uri, headers=headers, data=body)

    # You want to make sure their email is verified.
    # The user authenticated with Google, authorized your
    # app, and now you've verified their email through Google!
    if userinfo_response.json().get("email_verified"):
        unique_id = userinfo_response.json()["sub"]
        users_email = userinfo_response.json()["email"]
        picture = userinfo_response.json()["picture"]
        username = userinfo_response.json()["given_name"]
    else:
        return "User email not available or not verified by Google.", 400

    
    user = User.query.filter(User.google_sub==unique_id).first()
    login_user(user)
```

```
def get_google_provider_cfg():
    return requests.get(GOOGLE_DISCOVERY_URL).json()
```

My thoughts are maybe I have to set up a google drive endpoint to be able to send api requests to with the same token? Im not quite sure.

Comment: Hi there @kingkyle! After studying your question it is not clear for me if the issue comes from the Flask usage or Python. To prevent framework misconfigurations, could you please share a standalone Python code that replicates the problematic behaviour? [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) you can find an example of Drive API management in Python. Please, feel free to ask me any question.